# How to run gunicorn & nginx on system startup? [Ubuntu 14.04]

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, startup, gunicorn

I got a VPS that runs a django app w/ gunicorn & nginx.
right now im starting the whole thing by runnig:

```
cd /srv/OmegaManager
gunicorn -c /srv/gunicorn_config.py OmegaManager.wsgi
sudo service nginx start
```

How can i make a script that start those services that way on system startup?
I'm pretty new to linux, so please be well explained :)

OS: Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 5):

I suppose simplest solution for novice user (must work without problems) is put these commands to file /etc/rc.local (it must be in your system by default). This file executed during startup in most linux systems.

Place commands before last line with `exit 0`.

Make sure /etc/rc.local is executable (again, it must be OK by default).